# Año cero en python

Tags: python, datetime, calendario

Un saludo estimada comunidad

Tengo esta inquietud, con la función de módulo python **datetime** quisiera setear la fecha de inicio el **año 0**, o el (anno Domine). He estado probando con diferentes combinaciones con datetime o timedelta pero no me ha sido posible setearla sin que me de error.

```
from datetime import datetime
Fecha_inicio = datetime(0,1,1)
```

y me arroja este error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-8a1c725b993c> in <module>
----> 1 inicio = datetime(0,1,1)


ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

Sólo me deja colocar el año 1, que entiendo que en el calendario gregoriano es no es el año 0, no sé si es una cuestión conceptual, pero en teoría no podría poner fechas negativas o fechas **Antes de Cristo** (AC)?

Comment: ¿Y qué dice la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) al respecto para dicho módulo nativo de Python? ¿Te has tomado la molestia de leerla?

Comment: El calendario es asi: Pasas del "año 1 antes de" al "año 1 después de", sin un "año cero" entremedio. Pregunta "¿Qué día viene después de 4 de Octubre de 1582?". Respuesta: el 15 de Octubre.

Comment: datetime.MINYEAR:  The smallest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. MINYEAR is 1.

Comment: [No hubo año 0](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1o_cero).

Comment: Hola Estimada comunidad, gracias por responder, Claro @MauricioContreras ahí estuve leyendo la docu y como bien dice **Candid** está como constante un "MINYEAR" pero ese mínimo es 1.  Entiendo entonces que no se puede partir al menos con esta clase datetime con el año "CERO" porque no está definido y menos fechas antes de cristo "AC" . Agradecido por los comentarios

Comment: Para construir un calendario que represente fechas A.C., tendrías que hacerlo manualmente. Pero los objetos `datetime` sólo tienen fechas con años representables entre 1 y 9999, no hay cero ni negativos. Tendrías que escribir tu propia implementación o basarte en alguna ya escrita, como la Clase [`Time`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.time.Time.html) de [Astropy](https://www.astropy.org/). Saludos